# \smash still inserts unwanted vertical space

Tags: spacing

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\hrule
Paragraph

\vspace*{1cm}

\hrule
\smash{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Overlap}
Paragraph
\end{document}
```

(View output at [latexfiddle.com](http://latexfiddle.com/#/4l106fb2ma9a/60908))

In the first bit, the `\hrule` is touching the `Paragraph`, as it should.

Now I am inserting something that is `\smash`’ed in between, hoping that it would not affect the vertical placing, but it does: A small space appears between the rule and the text.

Why? And how do I avoid it?

Comment: There is the interline space between the hbox produced with `\smash` and the following paragraph. Add `\nointerlineskip` after the `\smash`

Comment: Another way: `\hspace*{4cm}\makebox[0pt]{\smash{Overlap}}%
\hrule
Paragraph`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you say

```
\hbox{x}
\hbox{y}
```

when in vertical mode, TeX will add interline glue between the boxes. The same if you say

```
\setbox0=\hbox{x}\box0
Paragraph
```

because at the end the two things are the same. What `\smash` does is, essentially, setting an `\hbox` and clearing its height and depth, then doing `\box0`. Thus what you see between the rule and “Paragraph” is actually the interline glue between the smashed text and “Paragraph”.

Solution: add `\nointerlineskip`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\hrule
Paragraph

\vspace*{1cm}

\hrule
\smash{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Overlap}\nointerlineskip
Paragraph
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### UPDATE

Due to changes in the LaTeX kernel, `\smash` now “leaves vertical mode”. Thus, in order to avoid a paragraph to be started by it, one has to enclose it in `\hbox`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\hrule
Paragraph

\vspace*{1cm}

\hrule
\hbox{\smash{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Overlap}}\nointerlineskip
Paragraph
\end{document}
```

Comment: With more recent LaTeX versions, you need `\hbox{\smash{~~~~~~~~Overlap}}\nointerlineskip`

Comment: Thanks for the update comment. (For those who came later, please refer to https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/108)